# codeigniter2 not able to load css with index.php url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, coda

I made a asset folder and in it a css folder. For accessing css files I do this:

```
<link href="<?php base_url()?>assets/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Which works 100% fine as long as the url is:

`http://localhost/web/`

But when i change the URL to

`http://localhost/web/index.php` 
Or

```
http://localhost/web/index.php/welcome/
```

It stops loading css or images. It must be noted that css is in the assets folder whose location is: `localhost/web/assets/` where as images are in the view folder along with the php files.

My .htaccess file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

plus my .htaccess file is in the application folder

Comment: What base_url do you have set in your config.php? If you look at the page with a tool such as Firebug what URL is it trying to load the CSS file from?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a rewrite condition to exclude the images and assets directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(images|assets) [NC]
```